# UITextView text colour not changing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitextview

I'm trying to programatically change the colour of a UITextView, however it doesn't seem to update. I have defined an IBOutlet in a view controller class, and then added the relevant connections in Storyboards. In the viewDidLoad: method, I have:

```
[super viewDidLoad];
[helpText setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[helpText setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

however, the text colour remains the same (Black). Any ideas?

Comment: did you hook them correctly?

Comment: yep, although I'm not sure what's happening - I also cannot change the text of the textview. It's all linked up correctly in IB though - even restarted Xcode to see if that would help but still have the same issue.

Comment: what about other controls, are they working?

Comment: other controls such as?

Comment: Are you certain that `helpText` is non-nil in `-viewDidLoad`?

Comment: It's just a UITextView on that ViewController - other links work fine in the application in other view controllers though.

Comment: @seamus Just checked - it's coming up as nil in -viewDidLoad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorted it:

I had a method called `-setHelpText:` which took the text to put in the helpText UITextView, however doing this (having a setter with the same name as an IBOutlet) causes a nil object to be created. Refactored the method name to something else and all is well :)

Comment: For anyone to whom it is not worked try to change textview color in viewDidLayoutSubviews method. It worked for me.      messageTextView.textColor = MyColor.myGreen()

Answer (score 0):

First Check Your `UITextView` add as Proper or not ???

Check that  `@property and @synthesize` is proper or not??

You can also try with

```
helpText.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

**Another way is**

```
UIColor *myColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:0.38 saturation:0.98 brightness:1.0 alpha:1.0];
[helpText setTextColor:myColor];
```

Comment: There is no difference at all between `[helpText setTextColor:...]` and `helpText.textColor = ...`.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya- this is not same ans..bCoz..may be op forget to give '@property or  @synthesize'...??

Comment: **I have defined an IBOutlet in a view controller class** said by OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
UITextView *t = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
[lbl setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[self.view addSubview:txtView];
```